# Meteor app deploying with Modulus

Tags: meteor, token, modulus, demeteorizer

I'm getting this error when I try typing `$modulus deploy` into terminal from my app directory:

```
Determining Meteor version...
Meteor version: 1.1.0.2
Bundling Meteor App...
undefined
[Error] Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/xx/Projects/Project1 && meteor bundle   --directory /Users/xx/Projects/Project1/.demeteorized
This command has been deprecated in favor of 'meteor build', which allows you
to build for multiple platforms and outputs a directory instead of a single
tarball. See 'meteor help build'for more information.


WARNING: The output directory is under your source tree.

Errors prevented bundling:
While building the application:
client/Project1.js:138:29: Unexpected token =
```

I get the same result with `$demeteorizer`. It worked on an old version of the app, then I added some features in new branch, merged, and now I'm getting this error.

**Already tried:** 
`sudo npm update -g modulus`

Comment: You must be using outdated versions of your tools, try to update it : `sudo npm update -g modulus`.

Comment: @saimeunt I tried that and it's still giving the same error :( .

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an actual error in my code. I had an extra closing curly brace somewhere.